# Kind of RDF ontologies for tourism

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology, rdfa

I'm setting up a tourism website and wish to use semantic web in it. I'm also interested in using RDF ontologies.

So, I was wondering if anyone could tell me, if exists anything for this, that says "This Hotel is located in Foo" or "This Restaurant has a 3 points rating in the Foo community" or "This itinerary it's for three days and it's recommended to a weekend trip"...

I'm aware that the [Dublin Core](http://dublincore.org/) covers a lot of the stuff related with digital information like online content, but, there is anything that fully covers this kind of info available on the web?

Comment: There are / will be recipes for tourism offers in the GoodRelations "cookbook" for developers: http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/wiki/GoodRelations#CookBook:_GoodRelations_Recipes_and_Examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure of anything exactly matching your requirements, a quick search turned up an [LNCS article](http://www.springerlink.com/content/mm812127v022hp87/) on an ontology for e-tourism but I've never seen it used in the wild per se

Much more useful is probably the [GoodRelations](http://www.heppnetz.de/projects/goodrelations/) ontology which is an e-commerce ontology which covers some of the things you'll likely want to express.  GoodRelations is quite popular and search engines like Yahoo already support reading RDF data expressed in the GoodRelations ontology.

Answer (score 1):

There are now two mature extensions to GoodRelations very much related to tourism:

- Tickets Ontology (TIO) - Tickets for admission to events, points of interest, flights, trains, coaches, etc.

  http://purl.org/tio/ns
- Vehicle Sales Ontology (VSO) - Cars, boats, bikes, etc. sales and rental

  http://purl.org/vso/ns

You can also use the first one to expose timetable information of any kind (flight, train, and coach schedules).